# Why does my CSS styles don't apply in the page?

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app

How can I style React apps using CSS from different files? What isn't this code working?

> Button.css

```
.Button {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

> Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Button.css';

const button = (props) => (
<div>
    <button className={classes.Button}>Click ca să dai muie</button>
</div>
);

export default button;
```

`<Button />` component is called after that in the statefull component.

PS: I'm using create-react-app v2 and React 16.8.6

Answer (score 0):

Applying a style from a `external css file` on a `react component` you should do:

import the css file like that:

```
import './Button.css';
```

**style file:**

```
.Button {
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      background-color: aquamarine;
    }
```

**Your component file:**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './Button.css';

    const Button = (props) => (
    <div>
        <button className="Button">Click ca să dai muie</button>
    </div>
    );

    export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only import the CSS to your component. And use the style as `Strings`.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';

const button = (props) => (
<div>
    <button className="Button">Click ca să dai muie</button>
</div>
);

export default button;
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work. Do you also know why the approach I used is not working?

Comment: @NandraMihnea, the reason for that it is the way the file it's loaded using the Webpack. This `import file.css` it's only used as a reference so the Webpack knows that it has to parse the file and add to the final CSS bundle.

Answer (score 0):

`create-react-app` [requires](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet) you to have [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) files in the format `[name].module.css`.

Excerpt from `create-react-app` ejected `config/webpack.config.js`:

> By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css

So if you want to keep using CSS Modules you should change the name of your `css`-file to **`Button.module.css`**.